# Testing a trigger click on a button does not work in Vue using Jest

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, buttonclick

Testing a trigger click on a button does not work in Vue using Jest.
When I try to find the button in the wrapper the test passes, but when I try a trigger click on the same button so a method will be called it does not work.

Here is the vue file snapshot of the button:

```
<v-btn @click="viewAppointment(appointment)" class="ma-2" dark small color="orange" id="view-appointment" data-viewAppointmentBtn>
  <v-icon left>mdi-eye</v-icon>
  <span>View</span>
</v-btn>
```

Here is the js file that contains the simple method call::

```
viewAppointment(appointment) {
  this.appointment = appointment;
  this.viewAppointmentDialog = !this.viewAppointmentDialog;
},
```

Here is the .spec.js file for the test::

```
import './setup.js';
import CoachAppointmentsRequests from '../dashboard/coach/appointments/requests/overview/Overview.vue';
import {shallowMount, createLocalVue} from "@vue/test-utils";
import Vuex from "vuex";

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Vuex);

describe("CoachAppointmentsRequests", () => {

  let wrapper;
  let store;
  let actions;
  let state;
  let getters;

  const $route = {
    path: 'appointment/requests/:application_id',
    params: { application_id: 123 }
  }

  actions = {
    GET_USER_APPOINTMENTS: jest.fn()
  };
  state = {
    user_appointments: [ {id:1, date: 'May 20, 2020'} ],
    all_user_appointments: [ {id:1, date: 'May 20, 2020'} ],
  };
  getters = {
    user_appointments: state => state.user_appointments,
    all_user_appointments: state => state.all_user_appointments
  };
  store = new Vuex.Store({
    actions,
    getters,
    state,
  });

  const getUserAppointments = jest.fn(() => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      process.nextTick(() => {
        resolve({
          data: [
            { id:1, appointee_id:2}
          ]
        })
      })
    })
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(CoachAppointmentsRequests, {
      propsData: {},
      mocks: {
        $route,
      },
      stubs: {},
      methods: {
        getUserAppointments,
      },
      store,
      localVue,
    });
  });

  it('click on the view appointment button calls the viewAppointment method', () => {
    const viewAppointment = jest.fn();
    wrapper.setMethods({ viewAppointment })
    const viewAppBtn = wrapper.find('#view-appointment');
    viewAppBtn.trigger('click');
    expect(viewAppointment).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Please I will appreciate your assistance with this issue.

Comment: Try add await wrapper.vm.$nextTick() after trigger('click')

Comment: after trying this @Anatoly I still get same error...
here is the error on the CLI...

`expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0

70 |     viewAppBtn.trigger('click');
71 |     await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
> 72 |     expect(viewAppointment).toBeCalled();
         |                             ^
73 |   });
`

Comment: did you try mount instead of shallowMount?

Comment: yes I did.. still same issue

Answer (score 2):

The `click` handler isn't called immediately after `trigger()`, but rather it's called in the next tick. However, `trigger()` returns a `Promise` that resolves when the component is updated, so you could [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the result of the call, as shown in the [docs example](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#trigger):

```js
it('clicked it', async () => {
  // ...
  await viewAppBtn.trigger('click')
  expect(viewAppointment).toBeCalled()
})
```

Comment: after trying this @tony19 I still get same error...
here is the error on the CLI...

`expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0

70 |     viewAppBtn.trigger('click');
71 |     await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
> 72 |     expect(viewAppointment).toBeCalled();
         |                             ^
73 |   });
`

Comment: @Techbola Can you link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I've used `shallowMount` to mount vue component and click on button wasn't working. The solution was to change `shallowMount` to `mount`.